# SQL 'COUNT' not returning what I expect, and somehow limiting results to one row

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Some background: an 'image' is part of one 'photoshoot', and may be a part of zero or many 'galleries'. My tables:

'shoots' table:

```
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Test shoot   |
|  2 | Another test |
|  3 | Final test   |
+----+--------------+
```

'images' table:

```
+----+-------------------+------------------+
| id | original_filename | storage_location |
+----+-------------------+------------------+
|  1 | test.jpg          | store/test.jpg   |
|  2 | test.jpg          | store/test.jpg   |
|  3 | test.jpg          | store/test.jpg   |
+----+-------------------+------------------+
```

'shoot_images' table:

```
+----------+----------+
| shoot_id | image_id |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |
|        1 |        2 |
|        3 |        3 |
+----------+----------+
```

'gallery_images' table:

```
+------------+----------+
| gallery_id | image_id |
+------------+----------+
|        1   |        1 |
|        1   |        2 |
|        2   |        3 |
|        3   |        1 |
|        4   |        1 |
+------------+----------+
```

What I'd like to get back, so I can say 'For this photoshoot, there are X images in total, and these images are featured in Y galleries:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| id | name         | image_count | gallery_count |
+----+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|  3 | Final test   |           1 |             1 |
|  2 | Another test |           0 |             0 |
|  1 | Test shoot   |           2 |             4 |
+----+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

I'm currently trying the SQL below, which appears to work correctly but only ever returns one row.  I can't work out why this is happening. Curiously, the below also returns a row even when 'shoots' is empty.

```sql
SELECT shoots.id,
       shoots.name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT shoot_images.image_id) AS image_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT gallery_images.gallery_id) AS gallery_count
FROM shoots
LEFT JOIN shoot_images ON shoots.id=shoot_images.shoot_id
LEFT JOIN gallery_images ON shoot_images.image_id=gallery_images.image_id
ORDER BY shoots.id DESC
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
     shoots.id,
     shoots.name,
     COUNT(DISTINCT shoot_images.image_id) AS image_count,
     COUNT(DISTINCT gallery_images.gallery_id) AS gallery_count
FROM shoots
LEFT JOIN shoot_images ON shoots.id=shoot_images.shoot_id
LEFT JOIN gallery_images ON shoot_images.image_id=gallery_images.image_id
GROUP BY 1, 2 -- Added this line
ORDER BY shoots.id DESC
```

Note: The SQL standard allows `GROUP BY` to be given either column names or column numbers, so `GROUP BY 1, 2` is equivalent to `GROUP BY shoots.id, shoots.name` in this case. There are many who consider this "bad coding practice" and advocate always using the column names, but I find it makes the code a lot more readable and maintainable and I've been writing SQL since before many users on this site were born, and it's never cause me a problem using this syntax.

FYI, the reason you were getting one row before, and not getting and error, is that in mysql, unlike any other database I know, you are allowed to omit the `group by` clause when using aggregating functions. In such cases, instead of throwing a syntax exception, mysql returns the *first* row for each unique combination of non-aggregate columns.

Although at first this may seem abhorrent to SQL purists, it can be incredibly handy!

Comment: Thanks - this is really helpful, both as a quick fix and for the thorough explanation. I'll read up on GROUP BY now to fully understand it in context.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the MySQL function group by.